# Changing height of a telerik:combobox control

Tags: textbox, telerik

How can I change the height of textbox in telerik:combobox control?

This is the code I'm using:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="ifgcboSearch" runat="server" Width="430px" OnItemDataBound="ifgcboSearch_ItemDataBound"
  Skin="Office2007" EnableLoadOnDemand="True" EnableVirtualScrolling="True" OnItemsRequested="ifgcboSearch_ItemsRequested"
  ShowMoreResultsBox="True" ValidationGroup="Search" ShowToggleImage="false" >
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

The Telerik-prescribed method is to modify the CSS class applied to the input element of the Combobox:

```
.ComboBoxInput_Office2007
{
  ...
  height: 50px;
}
```

(From http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet/combobox/combosetheight.html)

Comment: You can easily experiment with style changes like this by using tools like Firebug in FireFox. You can make changes and in real-time see how they affect the RadControls.